# How do I forward iMessages from my computer to my Android phone?

Tags: macos, messages, iphone, android

Last week, I had an iPhone 4s, an iPad mini, and a Macbook Pro. My cell phone plan was connected to my iPhone, and I set up text forwarding so that text messages from my phone would also load on my iPad and my Macbook Pro.

Three days ago, I lost my iPhone. To fill the gaping hole in my life, I swapped my cell phone plan to work with my dad's old Samsung Galaxy S2.

Now I can send texts from my phone, and iMessages from my iPad and laptop.

Two questions:

1. How can I get iMessage to forward messages as texts to my Galaxy S2?
2. Is it possible to get my iPad and my laptop to synchronize with texts sent from my Galaxy S2?

All I want is to have my iMessages and my texts in the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of third party solutions to this problem which the first party (Apple) has never resolved. Most of them involve forwarding your messages to a server somewhere, where they'll use a cell phone gateway to forward them as SMS to a phone you choose. Obviously, this represents a significant security vulnerability, as whoever owns the server has full access to your messages which could contain sensitive information.

The only way around this vulnerability is to own the server yourself, which is basically what PieMessage does. It's an open source project hosted on [Github](https://github.com/bboyairwreck/PieMessage), also available on the App Store somewhere. I haven't actually tried it out yet -- I don't have an iMac that stays at home all day to use as the server -- but it [seems](http://www.trustedreviews.com/how-tos/piemessage-how-to-use-imessage-on-your-android-phone) [to](https://9to5mac.com/2016/05/03/piemessage-imessage-open-source-android-app/) [have](http://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/5/4/11591008/piemessage-imessage-android) [trusted reviews](http://www.technobuffalo.com/2016/05/04/imessage-on-android-piemessage-finds-a-clever-solution/).